# Remote Access using Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote desktop type software that the client need not install anything…](https://superuser.com/questions/119399/remote-desktop-type-software-that-the-client-need-not-install-anything)

I'm hoping to try and do some trans-atlantic tech support for my in-laws.
Both my machine and theirs are running Windows 7 Home Premium.

I read in  [this HowToGeek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/turn-on-remote-desktop-in-windows-vista/) that the Home editions of Windows 7 and Vista don't support remote access.

What's the most straightforward way for me to access their machine - bearing in mind that they are a retired couple and this is their first computer and therefore anything that needs to happen at their end needs to be super simple.

Free would be prefered but if there is a good paid for solution I'd consider it.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of this: http://superuser.com/questions/119399/remote-desktop-type-software-that-the-client-need-not-install-anything/119423#119423 Will give Team Viewer a try

Comment: I don't think this question duplicated the data in that other question. Oh well. I did create a [discussion about Remote Destkop on Windows 7 Home Premium](http://superuser.com/q/680541/45163), which may help answer the original intent of this question.

Answer (score 3):

[TeamViewer Portable](http://www.teamviewer.com/download/version_5x/TeamViewerPortable.zip) for you, and [TeamViewer Quick Support](http://www.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerQS.exe) for the other party. Very easy to use, neither party has to install anything. I highly recommend it. Free of course.

Comment: when installing take care you choose non-professional and private use, so for home use you can use it as free and unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [the full version of TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/download/index.aspx) for both of you. Having TeamViewer preinstalled on their computer and configured with a default password means you don't have to ask them to open TeamViewerQS and read off the password (which may not be straightforward for a retired couple on their first computer). And on your side, there's not that much reason to use TeamViewer Portable instead of the full version on your own computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can give [Microsoft SharedView](http://connect.microsoft.com/site/sitehome.aspx?SiteID=94) a try. It's very simple to use.
If they can use the internet then they would be able to use this app.