# what's the remote desktop software that requires least configuration on client side?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote desktop type software that the client need not install anything…](https://superuser.com/questions/119399/remote-desktop-type-software-that-the-client-need-not-install-anything)

I need to help my sister in Bangkok maintain her PC (running Windows XP), and since she's not very computer literate, I think a remote desktop software would be the best option.

However, I'm not physically there to install and configure the remote desktop client on her computer. Is there any way that I can help her with the installation and configuration (probably sending her a script which she could just execute and get it done)? She can do basic installation of Windows app (just click on Next), but further configuration could be too much for her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ammyy.com

No setup, no installation, no router configuration, completely free*. Download the executable and run it, have your sister click start and read you her ID number. You download the exe file, run it, go into the "operator" tab, enter her ID, and click connect. She will be prompted to allow your connection, and when she does, you will be connected.

I've used Ammyy many, many times to help out family and friends; it's way simpler than setting up VNC or RDP over an internet connection. Gets you out of all that sticky port forwarding or VPN connections, and you won't have to walk your sister through configuring any clients on her end. All she has to do is download the program, run it, click a button and read you a number.

Also, performance is surprisingly good; I personally get speeds close to using RDP over an internet connection, but it's going to depend somewhat on where you are in relation to Bangkok.

Edit: *by completely free, I meant for personal use. There appear to also be restrictions of 15 hours per month on the free license (they state "possible" restirictions); I've never used it that frequently, so I've never come across that. It's not open source or freeware, but for one-off connections (such as helping out your sister), you really can't do better. Sorry if my original post was misleading, I hope this clarifies.

Comment: this works like a charm! it's the easiest solution indeed!

Answer (score 2):

[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) (free for personal use, Windows, Linux, Mac, iOS/Android) is fairly simple to set up. It can be installed or run without installation, so just a couple of clicks and you're ready to go. You'll have to send your sister a PIN and connection number but this is probably the easiest way of doing it, unless you want to set up VNC and port forwarding.

Comment: Free for non-commercial use or something like that. It's not freeware.

Comment: @Daniel Beck - apologies, it's free for personal use, while business licenses are a one-off payment for a lifetime use. Post edited.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the most success with [Crossloop](http://www.crossloop.com/).

Answer (score 1):

From what I have used the one with the least configuration is [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/). This assumes that her router does not block ports and has UPnP enabled. Otherwise you might have to open a port.

Comment: 30 seconds slower :)