# what's the remote desktop software that requires least configuration on client side?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the remote desktop software that requires least configuration on client side?](https://superuser.com/questions/282488/whats-the-remote-desktop-software-that-requires-least-configuration-on-client-si)

I need to help my sister in Bangkok maintain her PC (running Windows XP), and since she's not very computer literate. I think a remote desktop software would be the best option.

However, I'm not physically there to install and configure the remote desktop client on her computer. Is there any way that I can help her with the installation and configuration (probably sending her a script which she could just execute and get it done)? She can do basic installation of Windows app (just click on Next), but configuration could be too much for her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ammyy.com

No setup, no installation, no router configuration, completely free. Download the executable and run it, have your sister click start and read you her ID number. You download the exe file, run it, go into the "operator" tab, enter her ID, and click connect. She will be prompted to allow your connection, and when she does, you will be connected.

I've used Ammyy many, many times to help out family and friends; it's way simpler than setting up VNC or RDP over an internet connection. Gets you out of all that sticky port forwarding or VPN connections, and you won't have to walk your sister through configuring any clients on her end. All she has to do is download the program, run it, click a button and read you a number.

Also, performance is surprisingly good; I personally get speeds close to using RDP over an internet connection, but it's going to depend somewhat on where you are in relation to Bangkok.

Answer (score 1):

[Go To Assist Express](http://gotoassist.com) is an excellent tool and has no client-side configuration but, unfortunately, it's not free.